# Scala 2.11.8 lambda confusion `a: => A` vs `a: () => A`

Tags: scala, lambda

After ripping my hair out for several hours trying to get a more complex piece of code to compile, I simplified my confusion down to this simple issue.

I had thought that `a: => A` was a zero argument function returning `A` just like `a: () => A` or `a: Function0[A]`. Apparently, this is not the case at all, and the root of my confusion.

Curiously, I can't declare a local var/val of type `=> A`, I can only use that type for function arguments.

In hindsight, I would guess that this a lazy evaluation notation, not an actual function? Is this true? That is really confusing to use the function arrow for a non-function.

```
  // Compiler Error: Expression of type A doesn't conform to expected type () => A
  def notFunction0_1[A](a: => A) { val b: Function0[A] = a }

  // Compiler Error: Expression of type A doesn't conform to expected type () => A
  def notFunction0_2[A](a: => A) { val b: () => A = a }

  // Compiles. Also this matches inferred type of simply A.
  def justPlainA[A](a: => A) { val b: A = a }

  // While I can declare function arguments of type `=> A`, I can't declare local variables of the same type.
  def noLocal[A](a: => A) { val b: => A = a }
```